# Clarifications on the Gelfand triple $V \subset H \subset V^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $V$ and $H$ be two Hilbert spaces such that $V \subset H$ with continuous and dense injection.
Then we have
$$V \subset H \cong H' \hookrightarrow V',$$
where $\cong$ means that there exists an isometric isomorphism and $\hookrightarrow$ means that there exists a continuous injective map.

My question is: can we always find a Hilbert $V^* \cong V'$ such that $H \subset V^*$ with continuous and dense injection ?
This is for instance the case for
$$
V=\left\{u \in {\mathbb{R}}^{\mathbb{N}}; \quad \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} n^2 u_n^2<+\infty\right\},
\qquad
H=\left\{u \in {\mathbb{R}}^{\mathbb{N}}; \quad \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} u_n^2<+\infty\right\},
\qquad
V^*=\left\{u \in {\mathbb{R}}^{\mathbb{N}}; \quad \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} u_n^2<+\infty\right\}
.$$
I'm asking for a "real" inclusion, i.e. in the algebraic sense.

Comment: what is the difference between $\subset$ and $\hookrightarrow$ in your question?

Comment: $V \subset H$ means: for every $u \in V$ we have $u \in H$; whereas $H' \hookrightarrow V'$ means that there exists $J:H' \longrightarrow V'$ injective and continuous (here defined by $J(L)=L_{| V}$, the restriction to $V$).